# Distinct method repeat the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, distinct

i get repetitive rows when using the following :

```
 DataTable dt = list.AsEnumerable().Distinct().CopyToDataTable();
```

Why `Distinct()` doesn't work ?

---

My datatable structure :

```
serial,doc_content,doc_name,selected
int   ,Byte[]     ,string  ,int
```

Comment: What is `list`? What is inside the `list`? Try with `list.Distinct().AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();  `

Comment: `var list = dt_temp.Select("selected = 1");`

Comment: `int,byte[],string ,int`

Comment: @just_name That code doesn't help much. What is `dt_temp`? And what is that sequence of types?

Comment: `serial,doc_content,doc_name,selected`

Comment: Which entries are in there multiple times? Give an example.

Comment: Instead of posting smallest updates in the comments, you should update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct` will compare object references since `DataRow` does not override the default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods from `object` to take into the account the values stored in the rows.

There is an overload of [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb338049.aspx) which allows you to specify your own equality comparer, and there is a [DataRowComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337583.aspx) class which implements the required `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` interface.

You can then use it like this:

```
var distinct = list.AsEnumerable()
    .Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Well `Distinct()` will call `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. It's only comparing "by reference" here because `DataRow` doesn't override `Equals`.

Comment: I didn't know about DataRowComparer.Default before - nice. Not sure whether it'll work with a `byte[]` field though; it depends on how it's stored internally.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `Distinct()` on a sequence of data rows. I don't believe `DataRow` overrides `Equals`, so any two `DataRow` objects will compare as non-equal.

You'll need to either pass an `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` to `Distinct()`, or project to another type first (e.g. an anonymous type, which already implements an equality comparison) and call `Distinct()` on the new sequence.

If you want to keep working with `DataRow`, it's probably simplest to implement the equality comparer. Although [`DataRowComparer.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer.default.aspx) *looks* promising (I wasn't aware of it before) it *may* not work in your specific case due to the `byte[]` field.

Personally I like getting data into more specific types as quickly as possible, but YMMV. Note that if you project the entire `DataTable` to a more specific type, you could write the `Select` part as a `Where` clause instead:

```
var list = table.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row => new { Serial = row.Field<string>("serial"),
                          ContentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(row.Field<byte>("doc_content")),
                          Name = row.Field<string>("doc_name"),
                          Selected = row.Field<int>("selected") })
     .Where(x => x.Selected == 1)
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

Note that I'm converting the content into a base64 string so that equality comparisons will work simply. It's not the most efficient approach, but it *is* easy :) If you don't need the content, you could get rid of that bit of the projection.

Comment: Could u give me an example ,how to do that ?

Comment: Is there any way to use `CopyToDataTable();` after that

Comment: @just_name: You'd have to convert back to data rows - but do you *really* want to? Personally I'd rather move off `DataTable` and `DataRow` as quickly as possible...

Comment: one more thing why don't u use `doc_content = (row.Field<byte[]>("doc_content"))` instead of ` converting the content into a base64 string`

Comment: @just_name `byte[]` uses reference equality, `string` uses value equality. (by default)